# How to create a histogram of annual events, such as cherry blossom time

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time, time-series

I have calculated blooming and ripening times for a specific variety of plant, based on actual temperature data from over 40 years.  I would like to create two histograms on a single axis; one for blossoming and one for ripening.  Surely there is a more straightforward way than converting to integer dates and adjusting for leap years…

Here is some actual data (years have been removed) in the form of `{month, day}`:

```
{
  {4, 3}, {4, 22}, {4, 15}, {4, 2}, {4, 18}, 
  {4, 20}, {4, 12}, {3, 30}, {4, 4}, {4, 24}, 
  {4, 26}, {3, 4}, {4, 26}, {4, 13}, {5, 1}, 
  {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 18}, {4, 9}, {4, 19}, 
  {4, 10}, {4, 20}, {4, 3}, {4,4}, {3, 21}, 
  {4, 19}, {4, 15}, {4, 17}, {4, 9}, {4, 17}, 
  {4, 9}, {4, 8}, {4, 23}, {4, 17}, {4, 1}, 
  {4, 10}, {4, 15}, {4, 15}, {4, 11}, {4, 15}, 
  {4, 19}, {4, 22}, {4, 11}, {4, 4}, {4, 12}, 
  {3, 27}, {3, 24}, {4, 26}, {3, 28}, {4, 16}
}
```

Comment: Please include an example of the output you desire.

Comment: For example, there is a question right below yours that includes how to create this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/r9uMh.png

Comment: Are those values `{month, day}`?

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the quick response…   Yes, the values are {month,day}.  The desired output is graphics - a histogram with two humps for each plant variety - one hump for the observed or calculated distribution of blooming dates, and the other for ripening dates.  The two distributions is not the problem - it's the conversion of dates in Mathematica format to integers so that different years can be readily compared.  I don't want to turn this into a calendar conversion problem accounting for leap years, etc.  I would just like an x axis labeled with the date in a way that will be easy to read.

Comment: Maybe I should just go ahead and write a function to map: {1,x]-> x; {2,x}->31+x; {3,x}->59+x; etc.  I'm just surprised that there isn't already such a function in Mathematica.

Comment: Or maybe I'm surprised that Mathematica doesn't accept times as an acceptable input to a histogram.  I could add a false year to the data to make it look contemporaneous, if that is the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two approaches.

We'll create a second dataset by shifting the given data by two months:

```
blossom = {{4, 3}, {4, 22}, {4, 15}, {4, 2}, {4, 18}, {4, 20}, {4, 
    12}, {3, 30}, {4, 4}, {4, 24}, {4, 26}, {3, 4}, {4, 26}, {4, 
    13}, {5, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 18}, {4, 9}, {4, 19}, {4, 
    10}, {4, 20}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 21}, {4, 19}, {4, 15}, {4, 
    17}, {4, 9}, {4, 17}, {4, 9}, {4, 8}, {4, 23}, {4, 17}, {4, 
    1}, {4, 10}, {4, 15}, {4, 15}, {4, 11}, {4, 15}, {4, 19}, {4, 
    22}, {4, 11}, {4, 4}, {4, 12}, {3, 27}, {3, 24}, {4, 26}, {3, 
    28}, {4, 16}};
ripen = TranslationTransform[{2, 0}][blossom];
```

---

The first method converts the `{month, day}` into the number of the day in the year (1 for January 1st, 32 for February 1st, etc...) and creates a histogram from that.

```
DayOfYear[{m_, d_}] := 
 First[DateDifference[{2011, 12, 31}, {2012, m, d}, "Day"]]

{DayOfYear[{1, 1}], DayOfYear[{2, 1}], DayOfYear[{3, 1}]}
```

> ```
> {1, 32, 61}
> ```

```
Histogram[{DayOfYear /@ blossom, DayOfYear /@ ripen}, 20]
```

> [image]

---

The second approach is more involved.  We convert the `{month, day}` values into absolute times, and then use `HistogramList` on the combined datasets to get bins and counts without yet constructing the graphic.  We then create a corresponding `DateListPlot` of the data, for the sole purpose of  getting access to how it creates date axes.  Finally we combine the ticks from the `DateListPlot` with an actual `Histogram`, reusing the bins but recalculating the bins for the different datasets, to get the final graphic.

```
MonthDayToTime[{m_, d_}] := AbsoluteTime[{2012, m, d}]

blossomtimes = MonthDayToTime /@ blossom;
ripentimes = MonthDayToTime /@ ripen;

{bins, counts} = HistogramList[Join[blossomtimes, ripentimes], 20]

points = Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], ArrayPad[Riffle[counts, counts], 1]}];
dateplot = DateListPlot[points, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, Joined -> True]

Show[Histogram[{blossomtimes, ripentimes}, {bins}], Options[dateplot, Ticks]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks Brett!  I'm still surprised that the functions DayOfYear[ ] and its inverse are not built in to Mathematica.  I especially appreciate your second suggestion and the hints about labeling the x axis.  I'll use 2011 as my fake year since it is not a leap year.

Comment: Great answer, I never would have known to pull the ticks options from the DateListPlot, very smart, I would have spent forever redoing the x-axis ticks manually.

Comment: You could also use [`DaysBetween`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Calendar/ref/DaysBetween.html) from the Calendar package to implement `DayOfYear`.

Answer (score 5):

`DateHistogram` was added in version 10.2, and uses date-specific bins and ticks.

I'll use the same `{month, day}` data as my other example, but instead of transforming the dates ahead of time, I can use `DateFunction` to provide the interpretation automatically.

```
blossom = {{4, 3}, {4, 22}, {4, 15}, {4, 2}, {4, 18}, {4, 20}, {4, 
    12}, {3, 30}, {4, 4}, {4, 24}, {4, 26}, {3, 4}, {4, 26}, {4, 
    13}, {5, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 18}, {4, 9}, {4, 19}, {4, 
    10}, {4, 20}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 21}, {4, 19}, {4, 15}, {4, 
    17}, {4, 9}, {4, 17}, {4, 9}, {4, 8}, {4, 23}, {4, 17}, {4, 
    1}, {4, 10}, {4, 15}, {4, 15}, {4, 11}, {4, 15}, {4, 19}, {4, 
    22}, {4, 11}, {4, 4}, {4, 12}, {3, 27}, {3, 24}, {4, 26}, {3, 
    28}, {4, 16}};
ripen = TranslationTransform[{2, 0}][blossom];
```

#### Weekly bins

```
DateHistogram[{blossom, ripen}, "Week", 
    DateFunction -> (DateObject[Prepend[#, 2015]] &)]
```

> [image]

#### Daily bins

```
DateHistogram[{blossom, ripen}, "Day", 
    DateFunction -> (DateObject[Prepend[#, 2015]] &)]
```

> [image]

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new function, even if I don't have it in 10.1.  Something I wonder about is that you are giving every day a year of 2015, whereas the OP wrote: "based on actual temperature data from over 40 years" and "a more straightforward way than converting to integer dates and adjusting for leap years" -- I imagine ideally this should be plotted in sidereal time?