# density/histogram plot for date-time data

Tags: date-and-time, histograms

I have date and time data and want to plot its frequency histogram. Ideally I want to be able to customize the bin size (for example, every 5 minutes or a day). Anybody has this experience?

Comment: Care to show the code you are working on/with ?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2333/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 7 I don't have the fancy functions Verbeia used.  One can still process the data as any other.  `Gather` and `GatherBy`, as Verbeia alluded to, are good options.

For example, starting with some random date data in [`DateList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateList.html) format:

```
range = AbsoluteTime /@ {{2013}, {2014}};
dates = DateList /@ RandomInteger[range, 5000];
```

And using [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateListPlot.html) with [`CapForm["Butt"]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799562/758485):

```
plot[dat_, style__] :=
  DateListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], style]]
```

We could bin by day:

```
bins = {#[[1]], Length@#} & /@ Sort@Gather[dates[[All, ;; 3]]];

plot[bins, Orange, Thickness[0.001]]
```

[image]

By calendar weeks:

```
bins = {#[[1]] + {0, 0, 3.5}, Length@#} & /@ 
          Sort @ Gather[{#, #2, Floor[#3, 7]} & @@@ dates];

plot[bins, Orange, Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image]

By absolute seven-day periods:

```
week = 60^2 * 24 * 7;

bins = {#[[1]] + week/2, Length@#} & /@ 
         Sort @ Gather @ Floor[AbsoluteTime /@ dates, week];

plot[bins, Orange, Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image]

By ten-minute intervals (with data covering a single day):

```
range = AbsoluteTime /@ {{2013, 9, 1}, {2013, 9, 2}};
dates = DateList /@ RandomInteger[range, 5000];

bins = {#[[1]] + {0, 0, 0, 0, 5}, Length@#} & /@
   Sort @ Gather[{#, #2, #3, #4, Floor[#5, 10]} & @@@ dates];

plot[bins, Orange, Thickness[0.004]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice, since I don't have `Mma 9`. But does this work for time range rather than date range?

Comment: @QiangLi Do you mean by hours of the day?  As in bins:  (0:01, 6:00), (6:01, 12:00), (12:01, 18:00), (18:01, 24:00) or similar?

Comment: Yes. Or even by 10 minutes, when I have a lot of data. Oh, just upvoted. :)

Comment: @QiangLi Added.

Answer (score 6):

Someone else will probably come up with something involving `GatherBy`, but I would like to showcase the [undocumented `TemporalData` functions I recently posted about](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/how-can-i-manipulate-temporaldata/30713#30713).

You could convert your time series (list of date-value pairs) into `TemporalData` and use the `Aggregate` function in the `` TemporalData` `` package like this:

```
timeAggregate[data_,basis_,method_:Mean] (* single series, or TemporalData head *):=
With[{tddata= If[Head[data]===TemporalData,data,TemporalData[data]]},
    If[TemporalData`ValidTemporalDataQ[tddata],
    Apply[{DateList[#1],Sequence@@##2}&,
     (TemporalData`Aggregate[tddata,basis,method]["Paths"]),{2}],   
    Message[timeAggregate::nottd]
    ]]
```

where the message would be something like:

> timeAggregate::nottd = "The data provided is not or cannot be converted to valid TemporalData."

This function converts the date-value pair into `TemporalData` if it is not already in `TemporalData` form, tests that it is valid `TemporalData` (using another undocumented function in that package), and then aggregates the data according to the time specification *basis*. The aggregation method *method* can be any function that returns a scalar from a list of values, but I presume you want totals.

Usage would be along the lines of:

```
timeAggregate[mydata,{5, "Minute"},Total]
```

So for example:

```
mydata = Transpose@{AbsoluteTime@DateList[] + Range[4000], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 4000]};

aggred = timeAggregate[mydata, {5, "Minute"}, Total];
```

You could then strip off the dates to use `BarChart` directly, or alternatively use the [method described by Mr.Wizard here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799562/758485) to make a quick-and-dirty bar chart of dated data:

```
DateListPlot[aggred, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> None, 
 FillingStyle ->  Directive[Orange, CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[15]], 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**New in version 10.2: [DateHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram.html)**

Using the example setup in Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
range = AbsoluteTime /@ {{2013}, {2014}}; 
dates =  DateList /@ RandomInteger[range, 5000];

Labeled[Grid[Partition[#,2]&@Table[DateHistogram[dates, b, 
  PlotLabel ->Style[b, 16], ImageSize->300], 
 {b, {"Day", "Week", "Month", "Quarter"}}], Dividers->All], 
 Style["Count", 20], {Top, Left}]
```

[image]

```
Labeled[Grid[Partition[#,2]&@Table[DateHistogram[dates, b, "Probability",
  PlotLabel ->Style[b, 16], ImageSize->300], 
 {b, {"Day", "Week", "Month", "Quarter"}}], Dividers->All], 
 Style["Probability", 20], {Top, Left}]
```

[image]